# Can't use sudo's arguments as non-root in Fedora 16

Tags: android, sudo, sudoers, fedora-16

I am using a long-installed Fedora 16 box, and whenever I type "sudo -v", "sudo -l", etc. as a regular user (non-root), I get this output:

```
[user@* ~]$ sudo -v
env: -v: No such file or directory
[user@* ~]$
```

Something is causing sudo to think the "-v" is a process to run.

I found this when I was trying to set up NOPASSWD access for a specific executable that I added to /usr/bin, which also isn't working (It still asks for a password).

On a side note, do I need to reload the sudo config or something when I change the /etc/sudoers? Is the /etc/sudoers file even being used in Fedora 16?

Here is my /etc/sudoers config:

```
## Sudoers allows particular users to run various commands as
## the root user, without needing the root password.
##
## Examples are provided at the bottom of the file for collections
## of related commands, which can then be delegated out to particular
## users or groups.
## 
## This file must be edited with the 'visudo' command.

## Host Aliases
## Groups of machines. You may prefer to use hostnames (perhaps using 
## wildcards for entire domains) or IP addresses instead.
# Host_Alias     FILESERVERS = fs1, fs2
# Host_Alias     MAILSERVERS = smtp, smtp2

## User Aliases
## These aren't often necessary, as you can use regular groups
## (ie, from files, LDAP, NIS, etc) in this file - just use %groupname 
## rather than USERALIAS
# User_Alias ADMINS = jsmith, mikem


## Command Aliases
## These are groups of related commands...

## Networking
# Cmnd_Alias NETWORKING = /sbin/route, /sbin/ifconfig, /bin/ping, /sbin/dhclient, /usr/bin/net, /sbin/iptables, /usr/bin/rfcomm, /usr/bin/wvdial, /sbin/iwconfig, /sbin/mii-tool

## Installation and management of software
# Cmnd_Alias SOFTWARE = /bin/rpm, /usr/bin/up2date, /usr/bin/yum

## Services
# Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig

## Updating the locate database
# Cmnd_Alias LOCATE = /usr/bin/updatedb

## Storage
# Cmnd_Alias STORAGE = /sbin/fdisk, /sbin/sfdisk, /sbin/parted, /sbin/partprobe, /bin/mount, /bin/umount

## Delegating permissions
# Cmnd_Alias DELEGATING = /usr/sbin/visudo, /bin/chown, /bin/chmod, /bin/chgrp 

## Processes
# Cmnd_Alias PROCESSES = /bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/kill, /usr/bin/killall

## Drivers
# Cmnd_Alias DRIVERS = /sbin/modprobe

# Defaults specification

#
# Disable "ssh hostname sudo <cmd>", because it will show the password in clear. 
#         You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo <cmd>".
#
Defaults    requiretty

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on 
## which machines (the sudoers file can be shared between multiple
## systems).
## Syntax:
##
##  user    MACHINE=COMMANDS
##
## The COMMANDS section may have other options added to it.
##
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software, 
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL

## Allows members of the users group to mount and unmount the 
## cdrom as root
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /mnt/cdrom, /sbin/umount /mnt/cdrom

## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/fastboot*
```

Note: In the last line of my actual config, I did substitute my username for "user".

Also, I was told you can use *,[0-9], etc. in the sudoers config, and the fastboot command has arguments that I want to give my user all access to. (there are infinite argument possibilities, and I want access to all of them.) Perhaps I am wrong about needing the wildcard, but I have already tried this config file without it and it didn't work either.

And here is my sudo -V output:

```
Sudo version 1.8.3p1
Configure options: --build=i386-redhat-linux-gnu --host=i386-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --prefix=/usr --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libdir=/usr/lib --docdir=/usr/share/doc/sudo-1.8.3p1 --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-pam --with-pam-login --with-editor=/bin/vi --with-env-editor --with-ignore-dot --with-tty-tickets --with-ldap --with-selinux --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --with-linux-audit
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.3p1
Sudoers file grammar version 40

Sudoers path: /etc/sudoers
nsswitch path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
ldap.conf path: /etc/ldap.conf
ldap.secret path: /etc/ldap.secret
Authentication methods: 'pam'
Syslog facility if syslog is being used for logging: authpriv
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates successfully: notice
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates unsuccessfully: alert
Ignore '.' in $PATH
Send mail if the user is not in sudoers
Use a separate timestamp for each user/tty combo
Lecture user the first time they run sudo
Require users to authenticate by default
Root may run sudo
Allow some information gathering to give useful error messages
Only allow the user to run sudo if they have a tty
Visudo will honor the EDITOR environment variable
Set the LOGNAME and USER environment variables
Length at which to wrap log file lines (0 for no wrap): 80
Authentication timestamp timeout: 5.0 minutes
Password prompt timeout: 5.0 minutes
Number of tries to enter a password: 3
Umask to use or 0777 to use user's: 022
Path to mail program: /usr/sbin/sendmail
Flags for mail program: -t
Address to send mail to: root
Subject line for mail messages: *** SECURITY information for %h ***
Incorrect password message: Sorry, try again.
Path to authentication timestamp dir: /var/db/sudo
Default password prompt: [sudo] password for %p: 
Default user to run commands as: root
Value to override user's $PATH with: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Path to the editor for use by visudo: /bin/vi
When to require a password for 'list' pseudocommand: any
When to require a password for 'verify' pseudocommand: all
File descriptors >= 3 will be closed before executing a command
Reset the environment to a default set of variables
Environment variables to check for sanity:
    TERM
    LINGUAS
    LC_*
    LANGUAGE
    LANG
    COLORTERM
Environment variables to remove:
    RUBYOPT
    RUBYLIB
    PYTHONUSERBASE
    PYTHONINSPECT
    PYTHONPATH
    PYTHONHOME
    TMPPREFIX
    ZDOTDIR
    READNULLCMD
    NULLCMD
    FPATH
    PERL5DB
    PERL5OPT
    PERL5LIB
    PERLLIB
    PERLIO_DEBUG 
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    SHELLOPTS
    GLOBIGNORE
    PS4
    BASH_ENV
    ENV
    TERMCAP
    TERMPATH
    TERMINFO_DIRS
    TERMINFO
    _RLD*
    LD_*
    PATH_LOCALE
    NLSPATH
    HOSTALIASES
    RES_OPTIONS
    LOCALDOMAIN
    CDPATH
    IFS
Environment variables to preserve:
    XAUTHORITY
    _XKB_CHARSET
    LINGUAS
    LANGUAGE
    LC_ALL
    LC_TIME
    LC_TELEPHONE
    LC_PAPER
    LC_NUMERIC
    LC_NAME
    LC_MONETARY
    LC_MESSAGES
    LC_MEASUREMENT
    LC_IDENTIFICATION
    LC_COLLATE
    LC_CTYPE
    LC_ADDRESS
    LANG
    USERNAME
    QTDIR
    PS2
    PS1
    MAIL
    LS_COLORS
    KDEDIR
    INPUTRC
    HISTSIZE
    HOSTNAME
    DISPLAY
    COLORS
Locale to use while parsing sudoers: C
Directory in which to store input/output logs
File in which to store the input/output log
Add an entry to the utmp/utmpx file when allocating a pty

Local IP address and netmask pairs:
    192.168.1.88/255.255.255.0
    fe80::216:76ff:feb2:49a2/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
    fe80::214:d1ff:fed5:60e9/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::

Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.3p1
```

If someone could help me fix these 2 issues, that would be nice. To be honest, if someone could tell me why fastboot (Android partition flash tool, through USB) needs root access on my linux box, and then show me an easier way to make that run without asking for root access, that would be nice. My old linux didn't need root access for fastboot for some reason.

Also, please keep security in mind. I do not plan to allow everything to be run as root without requiring a password. Thank you.

---

I just found this in my .bashrc:

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

I forgot I added it. I had had some issues in the past with $PATH orders.

I removed the line, and my problems are now fixed. Thanks...I guess. *sighs I'm a power user and I always seem to fix my own problem. I can honestly say I have done so for almost 5 years now without anyone helping. This is sad.

Comment: I just found this in my .bashrc. "alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'" I forgot I added it. I had had some issues in the past with $PATH orders.

Comment: That would be the problem. You can either delete your question or answer it yourself!

Comment: Yeah sorry. I forgot to answer it 6 hours later. :P Updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found this in my .bashrc:

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

I forgot I added it. I had had some issues in the past with $PATH orders.

I removed the line, and my problems are now fixed. Thanks...I guess. *sighs I'm a power user and I always seem to fix my own problem. I can honestly say I have done so for almost 5 years now without anyone helping. This is sad.